# Bash Completion Problem with sudo on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: bash, vps, sudo

I have a VPS from Linode. I deployed Ubuntu 10.04 server. I added a user and put it sudoers file. 
when I write as a user

```
apti <TAB>
```

it comletes with tab to

```
aptitude <TAB>
```

but when I continue to

```
aptitude upd <TAB>
```

it didnt complete but on my desktop it works great. Even
worse if I try same command with sudo

```
sudo apti <TAB>
```

does not work 
I checked .basrc, .profile/.bashrc and /etc/bash.basrc files 
 and none of them were commented out so what is wrong.
By the way when I root it works

mine ~/bashrc

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I got my Linode (Jaunty) I had to install `bash-completion`. Give that a go.

Comment: yep, this will enable the bash completion you're used to. back in my day... nevermind...

Comment: bash-completion is already installed. Still completion does not work for sudo commands and without sudo only works for first argument

Comment: try `apt-get remove --purge bash-completion` and then `apt-get update` and `apt-get install bash-completion`, then log out, and back in, without more information, i.e. what your bash config files look like, it's hard to diagnose.

Comment: although bash-completion is installed. purge and reinstall solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should have something like this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

What do you mean "they are all commented out"? It's possible that something you need is commented out and that's causing your problem.

Comment: I mean only related parts exactly as your post

Comment: Denis I added mine bashrc

Comment: @gokdemir: "Commented out" means "disabled" and would have a "#" as the first non-whitespace character on the line. Also, in your question, it appears that there is a space before the `<TAB>`. Are you actually typing that space before you press `<TAB>`? If you issue the command `shopt progcomp` does it say "on"?

Comment: shame on me. I actually meant none of were commented out. Shopt progcomp says "on".

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to add the line "complete -cf sudo" to your ~/.bashrc file. This will allow bash to search for commands after sudo rather than searching for files in the current directory. I do the same with a lot of other commands too such as man and which.

Answer (score 1):

Check you don't have commented these lines out

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

once in your `~/.bashrc` file (probably ok) and once in the `/root/.bashrc` file where it is from unknown reasons commented out.